# Angular2- Organize website functionality in the form of module or component?

Tags: angular

I'm building a shopping website via Angular2 which have basic functions including product info, comment & rating, shopping cart, shipping, etc. i am not quite sure if i should build each of these functions in the form of "Module" or "Component"? What's the best practice to organize the project structure? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if your Project is on small level its enough to create single module but if your project very wide than you can split this into separate modules as per requirements.

> which have basic functions including product info, comment & rating, shopping cart, shipping, etc.

As per your need i think you just split this into different components and integrate those using routing no need to create different modules for each and every one.

For better understanding you can refer here too

[Angular2: Module and Component difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45803512/5043867)

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion. i just found there's an example to group the function into module by using the "feature module", which mentioned in [Feature Modules](http://angular2.axuer.com/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#feature-modules)

Comment: glad to know :)